# Android - Long Intensive Processing

Tags: android, android-activity

So I have an app that has long intensive processes by it's nature... Image Processing with a lot of value extraction and comparisons.

The whole process takes several minutes but as per the requirements anything under 2 minutes is acceptable.

The problem is that the task is so intensive the UI wont even load in until the task is complete. So I can't up date my users as to what the app is doing... Since the app appears to be crashed at this point.

I've looked into using an Async task but from my understanding it only can use 10% of the phones processing power which would increase run times...

Does Android have an accepted way of handling this? Or is there some form of an onUILoaded event I can tie into?

Comment: Asyncs are slower because they gotta be initialized every time which consumes a few CPU cycles before their code has even started. What you can try to do is splitting the workload into tiny pieces, not being processed longer than a few ms so the UI stays responsive. I am not familiar with Services so this might be your way to go but other than that you might try my method if everything else fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use an Intent Service that starts in the foreground. This is the little icon in your notifications like when you start Pandora. It's Android's best way of executing long running processes.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 1):

You definitely must use a `Service`. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Those are background processes that can run for long time without an UI present.

- Depending on what type of interaction you want you could use an `IntentService` which can at most post notifications to the system notification tray,
- or, if you need more detailed control you do a [`BoundService`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/components/bound-services.html), the service can start new threads and to its processing in the background and communicate with the Activity for control and UI update.